# How to use the docusign_esign Python library with a refresh token?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docusignapi

The ApiClient class in the Python docusign_esign library has a function for getting tokens called generate_access_token. But there does not appear to be any way to use the library with a refresh token i.e. to get another access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that the SDK (docusign_esign Python library) has a specific method to do that.
What you need to do is make a call like this:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic {IK+SecretKey base64 encoded}" \
     --data "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={refresh_token}" \
     --request POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
```

You need to use base64 encoding for both your IK (client_id) and post the concatenated data as a header. You need to provide the refresh token in the URL parameter.

Comment: Oh, fair enough. What do you mean by "IK+SecretKey", are the two keys just concatenated after base64 encoding them?

Comment: exactly! that's all this is

Comment: Thanks for this. It is ridiculous that the client library doesn't implement this.